# Is there a way to get single dependency tree for a maven project with sub-modules

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying to get the dependency tree of a maven project with modules for a certain artifact. But using command `mvn dependency:tree`, the dependency trees are generated separately for each sub module and one tree for the main/parent project. is there a way to get a combine dependency tree for the entire project, combining all the dependency trees of all sub-modules.